# Jsonify a model attribute specified within a Flask route

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to use a flask route input parameter to specify which model attribute to return in a JSON response. This is since I have numerous attributes, e.g.  'ozone', 'pm10', and so for each route I currently have to write a number of if statements to achieve this, e.g:

```
@hourly_data.route('/<pollutant>/<name>/')
def all_data4(pollutant, name):
    foo = Data.query.filter_by(site=name)
    if pollutant == 'ozone':
        return jsonify({a.time: a.ozone for a in foo})
    elif pollutant == 'pm10':
        return jsonify({a.time: a.pm10 for a in foo})
```

This makes each route rather verbose, so it would be preferable to have e.g.:

```
@hourly_data.route('/<pollutant>/<name>/')
def all_data4(pollutant, name):
    foo = Data.query.filter_by(site=name)
    return jsonify({a.time: a.pollutant for a in foo})
```

If I run the above code however, I get AttributeError: 'Data' object has no attribute 'pollutant'.

How can I achieve my aim so that I avoid all the extra lines of code which I currently need (as in the first example)?

Comment: I think you want `getattr(a, pollutant)`, but your first and second code samples are completely different so I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I mislablled a variable in the second piece of code, so I just edited it and hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: @paulos Would `pollutant` be a placeholder for `ozone` and `pm10`?

Comment: @Paulos What does the model look like for data. That would also be helpful!

Comment: @Alex Hall Perfect!

Comment: Note that this question has nothing to do with flask or JSON. You simply wanted to get an attribute with a dynamic/variable name. Try to only include what's relevant to your problem in a question. Otherwise people searching for flask and JSON may come here and waste their time.